# Add layout for all blog posts Orchard CMS

Tags: layout, orchardcms

I'm trying to add layout for all blog posts. I have added part Layout for BlogPost content type. Now I can add layout for blog post one by one. So, how I can add existing layout for all blog posts in blog?

Comment: Did you research "shape alternates" already?

Comment: Yes, but how  I can override blog post to show layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a Layout from /Admin/Contents/Create/Layout, save it and then in your blogposts, use the option "Use existing layout: " in order to get your layout.

Comment: I have created it, and choose in blogpost, but body of BlogPost placed above layout, Comments under layout. I'm trying to override BlogPost.Detail, but I have just @Display(Model.Content) in this file, so can I override displaying  Layout in  BlogPost.Detail, and place all other parts and fields of blog inside Layout?

Comment: If you have layout, then you do not need body... Include it in your layout. The second otpion is forget layout and create it in BlogPost.Detail view. There, you can display title like Model.ContentItem.TitlePart.Title, body part as @Html.Raw(Model.ContentItem.BodyPart.Text) etc

Comment: I understand that if I override BlogPost.Detail Layout will not visible. Right? 
What your mean "Include it in your layout"? I need to add Body Part for every Blog post?

Comment: I mean that add an html element to layout and put all body info there.... And remove body part or leave it empty

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand, I have layout with empty canvas where I need to show blog post [link](http://take.ms/zI3HO)
How I can show Blog Post here?

Comment: In empty Canvas, add agrid, add a row (1 column) and add HTML content element....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118983/discussion-between-urbanit-and--).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding new layer with `ContentType` rule, like this:

```cs
ContentType("BlogPost")
```

[image]

Then you can add your blog post special widgets to this layer including a `Layout Widget`, as you want.

Comment: It works, but how I can place all parts of blogpost inside this Layout Widget?